# How can I secure-wipe free space?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, delete

Any way that I can securely wipe free internal storage on Android? I am not talking about secure deleting, but just wiping whatever is possible to recover.

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable method is to manually copy large non-sensitive files (such as Linux images or the LibreOffice Installer Setup File) to the partition that you wish to erase the free space from, delete and repeat it around THREE to FIVE times. Ensure the files you copy fill up the drive as much as possible, i.e. start copying small files when the large ones are too big to fit in the last remaining MB / KB of free space.

If you don't want to mess around finding files to write, you can use a utility called Dummy File Creator: http://www.mynikko.com/dummy/

This will allow you to create files of a specific size containing random data (ensure the Random File Content option is selected).

Comment: I quite like this. might try it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several apps claiming to help you out with this, see my [Secure Wipe](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_datawipe#group_457) app list. They support different sub-sets of actions (e.g. only wiping free space versus "secure deleting files", or only working on SD card) – so make sure to read their descriptions. [Secure Eraser](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.aiuspaktyn.secureeraser) might work for your case.

Comment: Nice and detailed list. I tried `Secure Erase with iShredder 3` and `Secure Eraser`. It eliminates most of data, but still a lot of files are recoverable. I am using `DiskDigger Pro` to recover files.

Comment: That's surprising, and not good news. Bad enough if it happens with one of those apps, but two? Did you try some of the others, e.g. *Andro Shredder* or *Disk Sanitizer* as well?

Comment: The result is same. About 1600 files are very well recoverable. However, initially there were about 22000 files.

Comment: OK, so it's "better than nothing" – but far from "working as expected". All those apps claim to securely wipe *all* free space, which they obviously don't manage. Maybe too much space? Tried running them multiple times? Not that I think that will make a difference (unless "free space to wipe" is selected "in random order"). Thanks for testing!

Comment: Yes, I have run them multiple times. Many of those 1600 files(mostly pictures) are partially damaged, but still can be recognizable. They are from deleted gallery items. One strange thing I noticed - none of applications produced low memory warning on device, which makes me think that the file they create to wipe data is not exactly as much big as free space. Unless app can suppress low memory warning. Internal memory(which is only thing my phone has) is consisting of 32GB. Free space is 6GB.

Comment: They might write in chunks, relying on the controller cycling through the "empty blocks" (see [Wear Leveling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling)). I don't think they address blocks explicitly (which might require root – which these apps AFAIR do not request). Wow, until today I thought "military grade security" (iShredder) was not supposed to have holes a tank can drive through – but now I'm not sure if it didn't rather mean exactly that :)